# Practical approach for design a todo-app

Tags: reactjs, web, react-redux

I try to make a todo-app using react/(maybe)redux. My goal is to have a client that cant communicate with server using RESTful API to fetch and update data.

I already wrote my server that can handle AJAX request and host it on heroku.

My next step is to create a front-end using react or react/redux. Im not sure what is the right approach to store and update data.

Should I fetch and update data directly from client to server? If this the case, I think I only need to use react, do I ?

The second approach, I guess I need to use react and redux, is to fetch the "initial" data from server and store in reducers, display and change whatever user wants. Then, at the end, update the data back to server.

Im still learning web dev. I really appreciate any suggestion or documents  that I can read

Answer (score 0):

React alone will be plenty sufficient for a small app.  As a rule, adding redux adds complexity and it is best used when many containers need to access the same state.

Comment: If Im constantly making CRUD requests to the server, is it still a good approach ?

Comment: yes, you can use axios to make the requests -> https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I have to re-fetch data after detele or update my todo-list, which would double the amount of time for each single request

Comment: Would this not be the case with redux.  All redux does is move the state from the component level to a single store. It will have no effect on the number of ajax requests you have to make.  Just make sure you keep the state at the topmost containing component. In this case, it would be whatever container houses the individual todo components.

Comment: I thought u said not to use redux?

Comment: i am saying that lol, sorry if my last comment made that less clear

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kp-NOggyz54 -> here is a good video to watch concerning react/redux.... the purpose is not to condemn redux but rather to encourage not jumping straight to redux before considering using react only.... redux is an excellent library and certainly has it place (multi-view apps)